# Commiting to master only?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I am new to `git` and currently setting up my repositories and workflow.

I develop sites and work alone, but wanted to know if I can just `commit` all of my changes to the `master` branch and not use branches at all? Are there any drawbacks in doing this?

I don't plan collaborate with anyone anytime soon since I am a new startup.

Comment: No, that’s perfectly fine.

Comment: The fastest reply ever! Thank you...

Answer (score 3):

It's up to you how you want to use it, you can use the `master` branch. There are no disadvantages.

But there are a lot of advantages to using branches which you can find [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-need-branches-in-GIT).

Comment: Thanks for the link, still learning about it and this helps a lot.

Comment: Welcome, here are a few more links, hope they help you.
[link1](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-git-checkout-remote-branch-how-it-works-wh)
[link2](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches)

Answer (score 3):

It's up to you. However It is always recommenced to use multiple branches. It has various advantages such as:

**You work on features independently, and so they never affect anyone else's work until it comes time to merge. You can do code reviews and targeted testing on the feature branch without holding anyone else up if there's a problem.**

**For example:** Assume that you're working on a feature in a seperate branch. Then for some reason, you need to make a completely unrelated change somewhere else say you're fixing the build.

With feature branches, you can just commit your current work in your branch, switch to default, make your fix and switch back.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much to everyone who commented! I created a branch called: `dev` and `commit` that to `master` I guess the more I work with branches the more I will create.

Answer (score 1):

No need to have branches, no.

Use branches when you want to split code logic if need arises, but nothing compells you to any type of workflow, it just has to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought but wanted to check with the pros here. So in the future if needed I can create a test branch for a new feature and see if it's good and then commit to master.

Comment: Yes, though it's actually : you test it on your feature branch then checkout master and merge your branch into master.